# CSS selector match certain value in style attribute

Tags: css

How can I write css selector for an element with specified inline styles?

For example:

```
<div style="top: 0; left: 0;">link1</div>
<div style="left:3px; top:0;">link2</div>
<div style="top:3px; left:0;">link3</div>
```

Then, I want to select `link1` and `link2` since they all have `top:0`.

I'm not sure about if I should place a space in `div[style*="top: 0"]` or not. How does the style attribute be setted? Will browser format the string in any format automatically?

---

Why I need this: I know query an element based on style attribute is not a good idea. But I'm writing user style, while I cannot modify the html page or javascript. The web page only modified the style attribute when events triggered.

Comment: Maybe `a[href="#1"]{` ?

Comment: Just an example, ignore the href attribute... I have changed them to `<div>`...

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned you have no way to change the HTML, one hacky way you can do it is to account for both cases, I guess:

```
div[style*="top: 0"], div[style*="top:0"] {
    /* styles here */
}
```

An alternative would be to use JS/jQuery if you are willing.

Example for jQuery:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).css('top')) == 0;
}).addClass("yourNewClass");
```

**Edit**: Didn't notice that you mentioned you cannot alter the page via JavaScript as well, but well, leaving this in just in case.